# Is there an equivalent to archmage special ability Arcane Fire in previous editions?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, adnd-2e, adnd-1e, odnd

I'm searching for an equivalent to the archmage prestige class ability from 3.5e, Arcane Fire (DMG, page 178), in previous editions (Player's Options, 2e, 1e or OD&D), but not 4e or 5e. Any official source is valid, including the magazines or campaign specific sources. It could be a kit ability, class ability or a racial ability too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Forgotten Realms has had, basically from its inception, the concept of “spellfire” (e.g. *Spellfire*, 1985). It also has “silver fire,” a related ability (e.g. *The Seven Sisters*, 1995).

Arcane fire, silver fire, and spellfire are all rare, high-level abilities that allow the manipulation of magic in its rawest form. They’re also known as “fire” but can do blasts of unresistable magic damage.

Spellfire is considerably more powerful and versatile, able to do many things other than blasts of raw magic, and those who wield it can power it from foes’ spells, rather than having to use their own power. Silver fire is massively more powerful, completely destroying any nonliving material in its large area and doing much more damage than arcane fire. Both silver fire and spellfire are heavily associated with the Realms goddess Mystra and her Weave, and basically rely upon her favor.

So arcane fire cannot be said to be either of these abilities. But it could be seen as a lesser, Mystra-optional approach to wielding raw magic in similar ways. Whether such a lesser option was available in earlier editions, however, I do not know—but I have done some searching on the web, and I can’t find any reference to any.

Comment: I remember reading about these FR powers and they were in my mind linked with the chosen of Mystra, not properly a class/kit/racial ability (but the gifted sure has a arcane related class). I was trying to remember if some outer planar race had similar powers (amnizu had an energy touch only). My knowledge of 1e and OD&D is really shabby, so I will await sometime for another answers, and if not, upvote and accept yours (KRyan) soon.

Comment: @Lucas Silver fire definitely is a Chosen of Mystra thing, not something just anyone can do. Spellfire might be, though? I am not an expert either, particularly in whether the mechanics for those editions actually exposed these things to player-characters in any fashion.

Comment: Spellfire is somehow inherent to some people. It's reflected in a 3.5 first-level-only feat and prestige class, plus a whole short rules section, all from the (oh-so-well-balanced) Magic of Faerun.

Comment: Spellfire was, like psionics, a random chance roll at character creation option, though I don't have easy access to the box my 2e FR stuff is in right now.

Answer (score 3):

OD&D, Compendium, AD&D1e and 2e do not have any such ability in the core rules.

Forgotten Realms had Spellfire as a setting-specific thing, as per KRyan's answer